# Absolutely Integrable

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I don't know if this is a silly question, but if I have $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and I know that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|$ exists, can I say that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f$ also exists?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you need to know that $f$ is measurable. It is possible that $|f|$ is measurable but $f$ is not. If $f$ is measurable, then the integral exists and $|\int f| \le \int |f|$.

Comment: @ copper.hat Could you give me a counter example?

Comment: Well, the integral is only defined for measurable functions, so I'm not exactly sure how to give a counterexample. Take $S \subset [0,1]^n$ to be a non-measurable set of positive measure and define $f = (1-2 \cdot 1_S) 1_{[0,1]^n}$. Then $|f|$ is just the indicator of the cube, is measurable and integrable, but $f$ is not measurable and hence not integrable.

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful.